# Material-UI table expand more than once

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hey guys I'm having problem figuring out how to make table in material ui expand more than once

Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-antonelli-uhl3w

I want the second level to expand further
Thank you for suggestions

Comment: Use React `children` to make it once would be fine.

Comment: @keikai Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [TreeView](https://material-ui.com/components/tree-view/)